# Angular2 Calendar Typescript javascript

Tags: angular, typescript, calendar

I wanted to calculate the no.of working days [that means excluding saturday and sunday] from a choosen month of particular year like:

For e.g.

If 2017 is a selected year and February is selected month,
Then Output should be like:

```
{
week1 : 3 days[working days]
week2 : 5 days[working days]
week3 : 5 days[working days]
week4 : 5 days[working days]
week5 : 2 days[working days]
}
```

Total working days of February,2017 :20 working days.

I wanted to achieve this in Angular 2, typescript.

P.S : I am new to Angular2 and typescript, You can say beginner.

Any help Appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: from where you are getting list of working days ?

Comment: @PardeepJain I am not getting from anywhere I give an example above that I want to achieve like this. I need to fetch working days according per week excluding saturday and sunday..

Comment: I also come to know that there is moment.js I can use but how to implement or how to use it in my app m confused...!!

Answer (score 0):

Good old javascript:

```
"use strict";

var daysExclude = [0, 6],
    days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wednes', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Satur'];

// val is a comma separated month and year
// e.g.: 7,2017 or 04, 2015
// it can be just a number too (5, 9, etc.) in which case code uses current year
function getWorkingDays(val) {
    if(!val) { return false; }

    var wCount, out = {start: null, end: null, days: []};
    val = val.split(',');

    // subtract 1 as month is 0 based
    val[0] = parseInt(val[0]) - 1;
    if(val[0] > 11) { val[0] = val[0]%12; }

    // if year not provided, use current year
    if(typeof val[1] == 'undefined') {
        val[1] = new Date();
        val[1] = val[1].getFullYear();
    }

    // get first day of the current and next month
    out.start = new Date(val[1], val[0]);
    out.end = new Date(val[1], val[0] + 1);

    // save only the day number (0 - Sunday, ... 6 - Saturday)
    out.start = out.start.getDay();
    out.end = out.end.getDay();

    // increase out.end by a 28 or 35
    if(out.end < out.start) { out.end += 7; }
    out.end += 28;

    // calculate working days
    var i = out.start;
    while(i < out.end) {
        wCount = Math.floor(i/7);
        if(typeof out.days[wCount] == 'undefined') { out.days[wCount] = 0; }

        if(daysExclude.indexOf(i%7) == -1) { ++out.days[wCount]; }
        ++i;
    }

    // calculate output
    out.start = days[out.start] + 'day';
    out.end = days[(out.end-1)%7] + 'day';
    console.log(out);

    return out;
}
```